# Defining recording area of MediaCodec encoder, MediaMuxer or virtualdisplay

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am using MediaCodec, MediaMuxer and VirtualDisplay to record events on my phone and then create a mp4 file with that data.

I want the user to be able to define what part of the screen should be recorded, and to do that I can set the height and width of the MediaFormat for the encoder, but I seem not to be able to set any offsets so I will always record from the top left corner.

Is there a way to do this in a clever way?

Edit:
Here is some code i use for setting things up to make stuff more clear.

```
    MediaFormat encoderFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, ENCODER_WIDTH, ENCODER_HEIGHT);
    encoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FORMAT);
    encoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
    encoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    encoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

    encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    encoder.setCallback(new encoderCallback());
    encoder.configure(encoderFormat, null /* Surface */, null /* crypto */, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

    inputSurface = encoder.createInputSurface();

    // Create a virtual mDisplay that will output to our encoder.
    mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(NAME,
            VD_WIDTH, VD_HEIGHT, DENSITY, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION, inputSurface, null /*Callback*/, null /*Handler*/);
```

Comment: I think you will need to change what you render to the virtual display, rather than change how the virtual display surface is recorded.  Might be easiest to do with a second stage, i.e. virtual display to SurfaceTexture, then render ST to encoder.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution. I however are not experienced working with SurfaceTextures. Could you point me a bit further to the right direction? I added some of the setup-code to my edit-section.

Comment: You can find some examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  The "texture from camera" activity receives camera frames on a SurfaceTexture, then renders the output with GLES.  In your case, you'd want to replace the Camera setup with the virtual display setup: create the ST, use that to construct a new Surface, then pass that to `createVirtualDisplay()`.  Render the texture to the MediaCodec input surface.  See how RecordFBOActivity.java uses the WindowSurface class (e.g. `startEncoder()`).  It's complicated, but once it's set up you can do all kinds of crazy things with it.

Comment: After reading the entire Android architecture document, it seems clear that SurfaceFlinger is well suited to exporting a cropped and composited view of the screen -- but I am also unable to figure it out using real code.  Did you make any progress here?

Comment: No I did not. I read all the code given by fadden but I have worked so little with SurfaceView so i never got anywhere. Luckily, the customer that wanted the application done didn't need this future so I stopped figuring it out when I got stuck. If you figure it out, please post it here (good to have for future work)! :)